# Buffer Pool in SQL Server FileStream

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, filestream, sql-server-2016

One of the best feature of `FileStream` is : [The SQL Server buffer pool is not used; therefore, this memory is available for query processing.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server)

I have encountered an issue that If I create a stored procedure for return file from my `FileStream` table, Will The SQL Server buffer pool be used? Is it possible to take advantage of benefits of `FileStream` with `T-SQL` and SPs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT sql buffer pool not use.

> **Accessing FILESTREAM data with Managed API**
>
> Accessing FILESTREAM data using Win32 Streaming has a number of
>   advantages over accessing it using TSQL. When accessing FILESTREAM
>   data using TSQL, SQL Server reads the content of the FILESTREAM data
>   file and serves it to the client. SQL Server memory is used for
>   reading the content of the data file. Accessing FILESTREAM data using
>   Win32 Streaming does not use SQL Server memory. In addition it allows
>   the application to take advantage of the Streaming capabilities of the
>   NT File System.
>
> Though accessing FILESTREAM data using Win32 Streaming has a number of
>   advantages, it is a bit complicated to use, compared to the syntax
>   needed to access it from TSQL. Before a client application can access
>   the FILESTREAM data, it needs to find out the logical path that
>   uniquely identifies the given file in the FILESTREAM data store. This
>   can be achieved by using the “PathName” method of a FILESTREAM column.
>   Note that the PathName() function is Case Sensitive. The following
>   example shows how to retrieve the PathName() associated with the
>   FILESTREAM data of a column.
>   https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

for test using buffer pool while read data use counter

SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Extension page writes/sec

SQLServer:Buffer Manager\Extension page reads/sec

Answer (score 0):

If you are going only read/write data, you will not get any performance advantages, because you will only trasfer data from Sql client to File system and back through additional node(SQL Server). But it allow to unify your data storage and use single approach to store your different data( relational data or not ). And of course you will get advantages if you are going to process unrelational data and relational data together inside SQL Server.